# How do I find the size of the longest subarray?

Tags: arrays, ruby, max

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of arrays

```
arr = [[1, 8, 9, 10], [2, 3, 7], [0, 2, 15, 4, 27, 3], [2]]
```

How do I find the maximum number of elements for all of the child arrays?  For example, in the above, the answer would be 6 since the third array has 6 elements, more than the number of elements for the other arrays.

Comment: FWIW: it could be done with a plain old good reducer: `arr.reduce(0) { |memo, a| memo > a.length ? memo : a.length }`, which I believe could be faster.

Comment: @mudasobwa: It's indeed 30% faster than `max_by` according to fruity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's so simple

```
arr.max_by(&:size).size
=> 6
```

Comment: I would use `size` rather than `count` for this. See http://batsov.com/articles/2014/02/17/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-13-length-vs-size-vs-count/

Answer (score 4):

It's really straightforward, even if you don't know `max_by`:

```
arr.map(&:size).max
#=> 6
```

Comment: Of the answers so far, this is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) on the array:

```
array.max_by { |i| i.length }.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
> arr=[[1, 8, 9, 10], [2, 3, 7], [0, 2, 15, 4, 27, 3], [2]]
```

Use [max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by):

```
> arr.max_by {|l| l.length}
=> [0, 2, 15, 4, 27, 3]
```

Or, the shortcut form:

```
> arr.max_by(&:length)
=> [0, 2, 15, 4, 27, 3]
```

And if you want `6` vs the actual array:

```
> arr.max_by {|l| l.length}.length
=> 6
```

Answer (score 1):

`max_by` is the way to go here but you can use `max` too:

```
arr.max { |a, b| a.size <=> b.size }.size
#=> 6
```

---

#### Benchmarks

```
require 'fruity'
arr = Array.new(10000) { |arr| Array.new(rand 10) }

compare do
  maxby_size  { arr.max_by(&:size).size }
  maxby_count { arr.max_by(&:count).count }
  map_max     { arr.map(&:size).max }
  max         { arr.max { |a,b| a.size <=> b.size }.size }
  reduce      { arr.reduce(0) { |memo, a| memo > a.length ? memo : a.length } }
end

#Running each test 2 times. Test will take about 1 second.
#map_max is faster than max by 2x ± 0.1
#max is similar to reduce
#reduce is similar to maxby_size
#maxby_size is similar to maxby_count
```